# Probability of getting exactly one pair on rolling five dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a game with five die with six faces (A normal dice). The player rolls all the dice and what I am trying to work out is the probability of rolling exactly two dice with the same number. For example, XXYYZ would not be allowed as it has two pairs. I originally had the following equation:

$$\frac{6 \times 1 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 4}{6^5} = \frac{3000}{7776}$$

But after doing some simulations of the game I've found the value is somewhere around $67\%$. Does anyone have any ideas to help me? I've tried thinking of it as a slot machine with 5 numbers and each reel has 6 numbers, but still no success. I plan to work out the probability of a tuple later as well as a quadruple.

Comment: The rules aren't clear.  Do you mean *exactly* one pair?  So $XXYYZ$ wouldn't count?

Comment: Is it exactly 2 dice with the same number and all other dice with distinct numbers? Or 2 or more dice with the same number but others with distinct numbers? Or maybe two pairs like 3,3,5,4,4?...?

Comment: Sorry, there must be exactly one pair so you cannot have XXYYZ. But I would also like to work out the probability of tuple and quadruple later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the condition is to have exactly one pair of dice with the same number and the other three to have distinct numbers - so all permutations of $aabcd$.

The repeated numbers can appear on any two of the five rolls and could have any of the six numbers ($1-6$), so there are a total of $\binom{5}{2} \times 6$ ways.

For the other three rolls, we have $5 \times 4 \times 3$ ways.

So the required probability would be

$$\frac{\binom{5}{2} \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3}{6^5} \approx 46.3 \,\%$$

If you could post the code you are using for simulations, perhaps we could see why the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot to add a method to my code to remove the times when there are multiple pairs.

Comment: Glad you figured out the bug quickly.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, when calculating the probability of getting three of the same dice and then the other two can't be a pair, 5C2 and 5C3 are the same number so I can't see how that would change the result, is it something I would need to change with the following "6x5x4x3"?

Comment: Yes, the $3$ in the numerator would go away. Pr = $({5 \choose 3} \times 6 \times 5 \times 4) / 6^5$

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom52$ to choose two dice giving a pair. There are $6$ ways to assign a number of eyes to them. Then there are $5$ ways to choose what number of eyes the first chronologically unique die showed. $4$ ways for the second and $3$ ways for the third. In total, the answer is $$\frac{\binom52\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3}{6^5}=\frac{25}{54}\approx 46\%.$$ Not sure how you are getting $67\%$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to solve for other patterns also, it would be better to have a settled formula for finding the number of ways, like

[$\mathtt{ Lay\;Down\; Pattern}$] $\times$[$\mathtt{Permute\; Pattern}$]

which involves multiplying two multinomial coefficients

For the $2-1-1-1-0-0$ pattern it would be

$$\binom{5}{2,1,1,1,0,0}\times \binom{6}{1,3,2}$$

or in the permutation form of the multinomial coefficient, where we can conveniently remove $1!'s$ and $0's$

$$\frac{5!}{2!}\times\frac{6!}{3!2!} = 3600$$

and $Pr = \dfrac{3600}{6^5} =\dfrac{25}{54}$

To illustrate the process for another pattern $2-2-1-0-0-0$ eg, in the full form,

$$Pr = \binom{5}{2,2,1,0,0,0}\binom{6}{2,1,3}\Large/6^5$$